# Error: Package: td-agent-4.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 (treasuredata)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, fluentd

When I'm trying to install td-agent in Amazon Linux 2 with that following command

```
curl -L https://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-amazon2-td-agent4.sh | sh
```

I've encountered following error messages:

```
Error: Package: td-agent-4.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 (treasuredata)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: td-agent-4.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 (treasuredata)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: td-agent-4.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 (treasuredata)
           Requires: libtinfo.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: td-agent-4.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 (treasuredata)
           Requires: libncurses.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: td-agent-4.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 (treasuredata)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

And when I've checked my OS version:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Please let me know how to resolve that issue, thanks.

Comment: You are running Amazon Linux, not Amazon Linux 2, that's why the package intended for Amazon Linux 2 doesn't work.

Comment: @jordanm any solution to install td-agent?

Comment: Looks like their latest versions don't support Amazon Linux 1 for RPM installation. You can install open source fluentd with `gem`

Comment: you can try td-agent v3 or even v2. v2 is supported for sure.